# Drawn Squares Constantly Flicker Between Assigned Colors

Tags: graphics, game-maker, gml, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-1.4

I am very new to GameMaker 1.4, but I have some experience with Python and C++. I have created a matrix of random ints between 1 and 5 inclusive to represent the number of stories each building on a map has. I want to use this to draw a 10x10 set of squares with lighter grey squares representing taller buildings. Unfortunately, I can't get the squares to stay the same color. They constantly flicker between colors.

How can I get them to stop flickering and represent their relevant values appropriately?

Here is my script:

```
// Random 2D Map Height Generator

/*
Generates a matrix which is used for determining 
 the amount of stories per building in the game.

 Then draws squares of different colors to represent
 the number of stories of each building.
*/

ct = irandom(1);
// create array
for (i = 0; i <= global.height; i += 1) {
   for (j = 0; j <= global.width; j += 1) {
      mapArray[i, j] = irandom_range(1, 5);
      if (ct % 2 != 0 && mapArray[i, j] < 5) {
      mapArray[i, j] += 1;
   }
   ct += 1;
   }
}

// make colors
one = make_color_rgb(0, 0, 0);
two = make_color_rgb(51, 51, 51);
three = make_color_rgb(102, 102, 102);
four = make_color_rgb(153, 153, 153);
five = make_color_rgb(204, 204, 204);

// initialize coordinates
ex = 300;
wy = 100;

// count columns

// draw map
for (i = 0; i <= global.height; i += 1) {
   for (j = 0; j <= global.width; j += 1) {
      ex2 = ex + 30;
      wy2 = wy + 30;
      switch (mapArray[i, j])
      {
         case 1:
            draw_set_color(one);
            break;
         case 2:
            draw_set_color(two);
            break;
         case 3:
            draw_set_color(three);
            break;
         case 4:
            draw_set_color(four);
            break;
         case 5:
            draw_set_color(five);
            break;
         default:
            draw_text(200, 200, 
            "ERROR: scr_mapGeneration, case not met");
            break;
      }
      draw_rectangle(ex, wy, ex2, wy2, false);
      ex += 33;
      if (j == global.width) {
         wy += 33;
         ex = 300;
      }
   }
}
```

I call it in an object with the draw event and execute this code with it:

```
script_execute(scr_mapGeneration);
```

I call `randomize();` in my initial room's creation code. The problem occurs in another room.

Here is a picture of what is produced, obviously this picture doesn't have flickering squares.
[image]

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: My guess is that the script is executing very often.

Comment: That seems to be the case. I am not sure how to make it only execute once.

Comment: Does gamemaker have a way to seed the random generator? If so, you could seed it with the same value at the start of the script before calling the `irandom()` and `irandom_range()` functions.

Comment: @user1118321 I'll see if I can find anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors are constantly new assigned with **new** random values, since the draw funtion is called **every frame**.

`randomize()` does have nothing to do with your problem, random always creates a new random, it just changes the **random seed**. ;)

You should call the script in the **create** event **once**, and instead of drawing the rectangles you **store** them in e.g. a `ds_grid` ([more info here](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/data%20structures/ds%20grids/index.html))
In the draw funtion you just draw the saved values from the **grid**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had included all of the text as part of a draw event. So the array was constantly remade. The solution is to separate the array-making code and execute it under a different event. I used the creation event for this.

I would provide a detailed example, but it's difficult given the nature of the GameMaker program, and the solution should be self-explanatory anyway.